# SPSS Add Cases - meaning of GT 7 LT symbols in Unpaired Variables list?

Tags: merge, spss

I've been using SPSS for a long time, but there's a small piece of it that mystifies me. In an Add Cases dialog box, when you have some unmatched variables or some name-matched-but-format-different variable pairs, what is the meaning of a greater-than or less-than symbol next to the variable name?

Here's the example. I have 2 datasets, Data_A & Data_B. 
These variables have identical format in both: CASEID, DISP4B, afu_link.
These variables are unique to Data_A: agerank (numeric), agerankx (string).
These variables are unique to Data_B: c0180x (string), CPCOUNTY (string), CTYCODE1 (string).
These variables share names, but are numeric in Data_A and string in Data_B: HHADULT, NUMADULT.

In the Unpaired Variables list, I have

```
agerank(*)
agerankx<(*)
HHADULT(*)
NUMADULT(*)
c0810x<(+)
CPCOUNTY>(+)
CTYCODE1<(+)
HHADULT<(+)
NUMADULT<(+)
```

You can see this in the following annotated screenshot:
[image]

I know that the asterisk indicates the source as the active dataset (here, Data_A) and the plus indicates it's from the inactive dataset (Data_B). I'm accustomed to fixing format mismatches by revising the conflicting variable in one dataset or the other. Ignoring the GT/LT symbols hasn't caused any problems (that I'm aware of), but I'm curious to know what they're trying to tell me.

I've tried the built-in SPSS help and searching online, but haven't found the answer.

I'd be grateful for any help solving this niggling mystery, especially if it's something significant that I should be paying more attention to. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the variables (and their formats) from both datasets ?